# How to add Separate Class for grid span from inspect element

Tags: sapui5

I have created a simple form with some labels and input values.

```
<f:SimpleForm 
      class="Width">
<f:content>
<Label text="Employee Name" reqiured="true">
     <layoutData>
         <l:GridData span="L1 M3 S6"/>
     </layoutData>
</Label>
<Input id="empname">
     <layoutData>
         <l:GridData span="L2 M3 S6"/>
              </layoutData>
         </Input>
<Label text="Employee Email" reqiured="true">
     <layoutData>
         <l:GridData span="L1 M3 S6"/>
     </layoutData>
</Label>
<Input id="empemail">
     <layoutData>
         <l:GridData span="L2 M3 S6"/>
              </layoutData>
         </Input>
</f:content>
</f:SimpleForm>
```

For example If i inspect this form L1 grid span is with width (.sapUiRespGridMedia-Std-Desktop.sapUiRespGridHSpace0>.sapUiRespGridSpanL1 {
width: 12.33333333%;}). I have increased some width for responsiveness.If i include this in my css it is reflecting to all other L1 span in my project.I have created a class and included beside the ui5 element like
(.Width.sapUiRespGridMedia-StdDesktop.sapUiRespGridHSpace0>.sapUiRespGridSpanL1 {
width: 12.33333333%;}) but its not reflecting.Is there anyway to add separate class for gridspan and include with ui5 element can anyone help me

Comment: Add your custom css... changing width in grid layout is wrong. There are 12 responsive columns. Means, change the column size to like L1-> L2(Take two columns on large displays, and as I said you have max 12 in one line

Comment: i have changed the colums but i am facing the issue with lnput fields i am having the input fields large  like(Large play ground material,small play ground material,large play ground finish,small play ground finish) i have given L2 for input field,if i give L1 its not adjusting in L1  due to this the form  is not responsive so for that i have changed the width

Comment: your qustion is still unclear. What`s not adusting? What do you expenct. Whats ahppening instead. a grid layout is per definition responsive, This of course, dosent work if your  Width css is temperaing with the width of the form

Comment: I want to create a class for form and add that class for ui5 element(.sapUiRespGridMedia-Std-Desktop.sapUiRespGridHSpace0>.sapUiRespGridSpanL1)

Comment: @Sophie Could you add a screenshot/ mockup/ wireframe to your question? Currently, it's hard to understand what you're actually trying to achieve. Seems like we're having an [_XY-problem_](http://xyproblem.info/) here..